# fix Error: Cannot find module 'crypto-js/sha256'

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I run the code, I get this error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:949
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'crypto-js/sha256'
Require stack:
- /Users/admin/Desktop/Full-stack development/blockchain/index.js
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:946:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:787:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Desktop/Full-stack development/blockchain/index.js:1:14)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1166:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:834:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [ '/Users/admin/Desktop/Full-stack development/blockchain/index.js' ]
}

Node.js v18.4.0
```

and here is my code:

```
const hash = require('crypto-js/sha256');

class Block {
        constructor(prevHash, data) {
            this.prevHash = prevHash;
            this.data = data;
            this.timeStamp = new Date();

             this.hash = this.calculateHash();
            }

        calculateHash() {
            return hash(this.prevHash + JSON.stringify(this.data) + this.timeStamp).toString();
    }
}


const block =  new Block('', {
        hello: 'world'
});

console.log(block);
```

I ran the command: node index.js.
And I have fully installed nodejs, npm.
Here is the version I'm using:
admin@Admins-iMac ~ % node --version
v18.4.0
admin@Admins-iMac ~ % npm --version
8.12.1
I don't know why my program is crashing, please help me

Comment: Do you have `crypto-js` in the `package.json`? Did you install packages using `npm install`?

Comment: thanks, looks like i haven't installed package.json using npm install